# Gradle init failing to create a project

Tags: gradle, fedora

This week I tried to give Gradle a go and everything worked fine in 2/3 machines I played with. When I try to create a new project by running either `gradle init` or `gradle init --type=java-library` I get the following error message:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
:wrapper
:init FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init'.
> Null value provided for binding 'junitVersion'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.809 secs
```

After that, my project tree is just this:

```
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

I'm getting this error with Gradle 2.12 on Fedora 24. The weird thing, though, is that every other Gradle's command is working fine with one project I have.

Could anyone help me solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me using Gradle 2.14, which I just downloaded and installed manually.  Also on Fedora 24.

Comment: Yeah. I did that and it worked for me as well. I forgot to give an answer to the question.